# how to do easiest group of filtering conditions in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller, angularjs-filter

I have four filtering such as **JobType,Experience,DateAdded and Salary** i want to do filtering as individual and group. For it i defined a filter as filterType in my controller and added to template like bellow.

in my controller

```
.filter('filterType', function($filter) {

      // Create the return function
      // set the required parameter name to **params**
      return function(jobs,workType,experience,dateAdded,salary) {
          var filtered =[];
          var wT = angular.isUndefined(workType);
          var exp = angular.isUndefined(experience);
          var dA = angular.isUndefined(dateAdded);
          var sal = angular.isUndefined(salary);

          if(wT && exp && dA && sal)
            return jobs;


      angular.forEach(jobs,function(job){
        if(exp && dA && sal){
          if(job.type == workType)
              filtered.push(job)
        }
        else if(dA && sal && wT){
          var exp_val = $filter('split')(experience,',',0);  
          if(job.experience ==  exp_val)
              filtered.push(job)            
        }
        else if(sal && wT && exp){
          var date_field = $filter('pastDay')(job.created_at);
            console.log(job.created_at);
            console.log(date_field);
          if(dateAdded == date_field){
             filtered.push(job);
          }

        }
        else if(wT && exp && dA){
          var exp_val = $filter('split')(experience,',',0);  
          if(job.created_at ==  exp_val)
              filtered.push(job)            
        }

      });      
      return filtered;
  }
 })
```

in my template

```
<div flex="20" flex-sm="100" ng-repeat="job in jobs | filterType: workType:experience:dateAdded:salary">
```

filtering is working as i had expected, The problem is suppose if i want to filter with set of filtering do i need to write the set of if/else statements for it. it seems as like a long work..

Can anyone suggest the best way to solve????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.filter('filterType', function($filter) {

// Create the return function
// set the required parameter name to **params**
  return function(jobs,wT,exp,dA,sal) {
    var filtered =[];
    var multiple = false;

  if(!wT && !exp && !dA && !sal)
    return jobs;


    if(wT){
         var val = multiple ? filtered : jobs;
         var filtered_wT = [];  
         angular.forEach(val,function(job){
          if(job.type == wT)
            filtered_wT.push(job);
         });
            filtered = filtered_wT;
            multiple = true;
    }
    if(exp){
          var exp_val = $filter('split')(exp,',',0);
          var filtered_exp = [];
          var val = multiple ? filtered : jobs;
            angular.forEach(val,function(job){
             if(job.experience ==  exp_val)
               filtered_exp.push(job);
             });
            filtered = filtered_exp;
            multiple = true;
    }
    if(dA){
         var val = multiple ? filtered : jobs;
         var filtered_dA = [];
         angular.forEach(val,function(job){
          var date_field = $filter('pastDay')(job.created_at);                       
           if(dA == date_field)
            filtered_dA.push(job);
           });
        filtered = filtered_dA;
        multiple = true;
    }
    if(sal){
        var filtered_sal = [];
        angular.forEach(jobs,function(job){
          var min_sal = $filter('split')(sal,'-',0);  
          var max_sal = $filter('split')(sal,'-',1);  
          if(min_sal >= job.minsalary && max_sal <= job.maxsalary)    
            filtered_sal.push(job);
        });
        filtered = filtered_sal;
        multiple = true;
    }

  return filtered;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this :

```
.filter('filterType', function($filter) {
  return function(jobs,workType,experience,dateAdded,salary) {
    var filtered = Array.prototype.slice.apply(jobs); // make a copy of the array
  if(!workType && !experience && !dateAdded && !salary){
    return filtered;
  }

  if(workType){
    filtered = $filter('filter')(filtered, {type: workType});
  }

  if(experience){
   //filter by experience, like workType
  }

  if(dateAdded){
   // filter by date, like workType
  }

  //     ... other filters

  return filtered;
 }
})
```

Comment: filtered = $filter('filter')(filtered, {type: workType}); how to take this parameter in filter?

Comment: "Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: job in jobs | filterType: " this error is occuring

Comment: what do you mean by "take this parameter in filter?" Also, please create a plunkr/jsbin that recreates the problem you're seeing.